# Implementing the "more filter" in C

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am wondering how to implement the more filter - as in display text till it fills the screen and move each line with "Enter" (just like in UNIX). I know ncurses would be useful, but cant find the appropriate method.

Thanks!

Comment: What about looking at the source code for more?

Comment: You can read actual sources of simple `more` variant, e.g. [from busybox](http://www.koders.com/c/fidED4951A4213C030ECDCC59834802D9D5E532F750.aspx). For `more` full ncurses are not needed; only getting a size of screen (which is optional too).

Answer (score 0):

Make a two buffer implementation

This can be an outline:

```
Read from file into the 1st buffer.
```

`offset = 0`

```
while `offset != total_lines_in_file`
  [1] show `max_lines_in_a_page` number of lines starting from line number `offset`
  [2] when showing the lines if a buffer end is detected, load the other buffer and switch buffer, and print remaining lines.
  [3] if the specific scroll keypress is detected make `offset = offset + x` (x = 1, 2 etc.)
```

Better have a look at the source code of `more` implementation.